# Alternatives to JUnit

Tags: java, junit

Are there any alternatives to JUnit? I have a head unit running a proprietary stripped down version of JRE 1.4.2, and JUnit is incompatible with this implementation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using an older version of JUnit. Start with the latest 3.x version, if that doesn't work, go backwards from there. I would be very surprised if JUnit 3.8.1 didn't work as JUnit 3.8.1 was released in 2002 and J2SE 5.0 didn't come out until 2004. All releases are available here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/junit/files/junit

Comment: +1 We were using JUnit with a 1.2.2 JRE. It was an older version of JUnit but it worked.

Comment: We ended up going to JUnit 3.8. As it turns out the only reason JUnit 4 was not working for us is because the 1.4 runtime doesn't support annotations, so @RunWith for pulling classes from another location wasn't working.

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe you could have used JUnit 4 but not use the annotations. I'm pretty sure JUnit 4 still includes all the old 3.8 functionality for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it'll work any better than JUnit, but there is [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html)

Comment: Quite sure TestNG relies on annotations, and therefore not a suitable alternative in a 1.4.2 environment.

Comment: Indeed, but earlier versions of TestNG supported annotations as Javadocs, you can still get one of these (but they are a few years old).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use TestNG as core unit test framework for Java project, because TestNG is more advance in parameterize testing, dependency testing and suite testing (Grouping concept).

also cover the entire core JUnit4 functionality.